# DedupeResponseHeader In Spring boot Gateway not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

i had a problem while trying to configure my gateway in spring cloud, I have added the following code in the yml file:

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  application:
    name: "gateway"
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, RETAIN_UNIQUE
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods: "*"
            allowCredentials: true
```

But when I receive the return response still includes `2 fields Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response header, this causes the CORS error below:
[image]

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxx/api/authentication/send-sign-in-code' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.
```

Why doesn't DedupeResponseHeader work here? Thanks everyone and happy coding

i tried changing `allowedOrigins` to `"http://localhost:3000"` but it still doesn't work and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. I tried to configure DedupeResponseHeader in yml config but this filter was not appling to my routes. I did not find why and decided to configure DedupeResponseHeader in code. This is how my routing config looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class RoutingConfig {

@Bean
public RouteLocator routing(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
        .route(r -> r.path("/api/v1/orders/**").filters(dedupeResponseHeaders()).uri("http://example.com"))
        .build();
}

/**
 * To remove duplicated CORS headers which might appear because they added by gateway and by downstream service
 */
private Function<GatewayFilterSpec, UriSpec> dedupeResponseHeaders() {
    String strategy = DedupeResponseHeaderGatewayFilterFactory.Strategy.RETAIN_FIRST.name();
    return f -> f.dedupeResponseHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, strategy)
        .dedupeResponseHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, strategy);
}
```

}